# How to make the facebook tab to go to a particular website?

Tags: facebook

We have a facebook fanpage and we would like to make a tab on left hand side menu bar such that user will go to a webpage after clicking on it.

Any idea? Previously, there is a static FBML app but now this app seems cannot be used anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Page Tab is just an Application running in `iframe`, which may be static page if you wish so. You'll need to host it elsewhere. To add Tab to your Facebook Pages you need to leverage Application with Page Tab details configured.

Read [Page Tab Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) about how to configure your Application to work as a Page Tab.

You may also want to [watch the Facebook Platform Overview course](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=fb-platform) (require Sliverlight), especially ["Page Tab Apps"](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PsodPlayer?author=yasser-shohoud&name=fb-m01-applications&mode=live&clip=8&course=fb-platform) part.